# SQL Server : TempDB high number of writes

Tags: sql-server, performance, tempdb

We use a SQL Server 2008 Web Edition on a Windows 2012 R2 server (32 GB RAM) to store data for an ASP.NET based web application. There are several dabases with news tables and different views which we query regularly (`SqlDataReader`, Linq-to-SQL) with different joins and filter conditions. The queries itself are longer and domain-specific so I skip an example.

So far everything worked fine.

Now we had to change such a query and extend it with a simple `OR` condition.
The result was that the number of reads and writes in the `TempDB` increased dramatically. Dramatically means 1000 writes of more than 100 MB per minute which results in a total tempdb file size of currently 1.5 GB.

If we remove the `OR` filter statement from the original query the `TempDB` file I/O normalizes instantly.

[image: I/O performance chart]

However, we do not have a clue what's going on within the `TempDB`. We ran the Query Analyzer several times and compared the results but its index optimization recommendations were only related to other databases stats and did not have any effect.

How would you narrow down this issue? Does anyone else experienced such a behavior in the past? Is it likely to be a problem with the news query itself or is it possible that we simply have to change some `TempDB` database properties to improve its I/O performance, e.g. autogrowth?

Comment: How do the execution plans differ with and without your OR extension?

Answer (score 1):

Start by analyzing your execution plans and run your queries with statistics (use the profiler). The problem is not in de tempdb, but in your queries. Then you will see where you select to many row which are temporary saved in de tempdb. Then you can change the queries or add the index you are missing.